# changing the ownership of a file in linux

Tags: linux, chmod, chown, ownership

I have a file "test" on an Ubuntu system owned by the root. The ls -l option is shown below.

```
$ ls -l test
-r--r----- 1 root abacus 373 Nov 12 19:19 test
```

I know that only the owner of a file can change its permission. But I want to know whether there is any way to read the contents of the file for an anonymous user.

Comment: You can look into `sudo`, `setuid`, and `setgid` to keep the ownership as root, but allow people to read it.

Answer (score 2):

No. As it is any anonymous reader can not read the files contents.

Right now the only people able to read the file are:

- People with uid 0.
- The owner. In this case the user called 'root', which is probably the same as the uid 0 user.
- All people in the group 'abacus`. (Check /etc/groups to see who is in that group).

Then there is a category of people who are not in that group and who are not the owner. For these the file is set to unreadable. You can change that with `chmod o+r test` or with `chmod +r test`. (The latter sets it for all three in {user:group:other}).

All of this assume no additional ACLs (e.g. SElinux) are applied.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add o+r, meaning, others can read:

```
chmod o+r test
```